# What do to with !Package inputenc Error: Unicode char (U+202F) (inputenc) not set up for

Tags: errors, unicode

I have tried `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{211D}{\mathbb{R}}` after reading the previously proposed solutions. Yet, my problem still remains and I am stuck. Please help!

Thanks,

Lucas

Comment: DeclareUnicodeCharacter is the correct command but the error shows that U+202F is not defined whereas in your text you say you defined U+211D

Comment: how come such characters got into a TeX source? what are you using to produce the file?

Answer (score 8):

U+202F is NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE so you probably want

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
```

Comment: I used this to replace the faulty unicode value by a random character (e.g. _) in order to identify visually in the generated pdf. It's a hack but it helper me fix my compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `\DeclareUnicodeCharacer{202F}{\,}` did not work, instead I got multiple errors about forgotten `$` and `}`.

The reason was that the 202F Unicode Character was inside my `.bib` file generated with Zotero.

The following command from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396775) helped me identifying the source, it was a space in a publication title containing "500 m":

```
\usepackage{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\def\UTFviii@defined#1{%
    \ifx#1\relax
    !!FIXME!!%
    \else
    \expandafter#1%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```