# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ⁡ (U+2061) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

Getting this error while trying to upload my paper to the Springer journal.

But it builds fine on my system.

Any help?

Comment: @moewe tod: Is it U+2016 or U+2061?  The tex error should indicate a line number.  Do you have anything strange on that line?  Some symbol you copy and pasted?

Comment: @Teepeemm it is U+2061

Comment: U+2061 is FUNCTION APPLICATION that is an invisible zero width character intended to  distinguish concatenation meaning function application from concatenation meaning multiplication,. You should be able to simply delete it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle How can i delete it? I am using Winedt

Comment: just delete the line and retype that line for example, the full error message from the log shows you where the character is.

Comment: Yes, it does show me the line number... deleted the line several times and retyped. unfortunately, that's not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

U+2061 is FUNCTION APPLICATION that is an invisible zero width character intended to distinguish concatenation meaning function application from concatenation meaning multiplication,. You should be able to simply delete it.

If deleting it is hard then declare it to do nothing add this to the document preamble

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}
```

Comment: David "The Hammer!" Carlisle, (+1)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes can you suggest a better tex definition for a character defined to have no effect on visual output? :-)

Comment: I stand in full admiration.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle when I use it, it gives the same error even on my system... I have tried it even before... Maybe let me check it on springer website after using this line.

Comment: @tod no, it can't give a character not defined error after you define the character. Please post a small example document that shows the problem.

Comment: `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}` with this it gives error: Undefined control sequence   <recently read> \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{}

Comment: Yes it has shown something on website compile.. but not in my WinEdt

Comment: @tod that is a _different_ error :-) and means you have an old latex, add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` before the definition.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2061}{X}`, so that the output would show where the offending character is hiding?

Comment: @Teepeemm , yeah this works too. You could place any character in the brackets.

Comment: @Teepeemm https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396766/1090

Answer (score 0):

If there is a part of the text where you think invisible U2061 is hidden then you can  copy and paste it to Microsoft Word using "Keep Text Only" option and the hidden symbols will be visible. You can delete them and then copy paste the edited text back into TeX.