# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+2003)

Tags: errors, symbols, unicode, input-encodings

I am new to LaTeX. I am writing my thesis and it was working fine, until recently I got slide in LaTeX, to which I wanted to prepare. So long story short it wasn't able to open, so I was trying few times which leads me to reinstalling my MiKTeX, TeXmaker (to which group here is using).

Long story short, I somehow got my paper format LaTeX to work, my new slide to open, but my thesis that was originality able to open, now I am not able to.

Initially it was saying

> ```
> Package Inputenc error : Unicode Char (U+FB01)
> ```

so I check the line, removing some spacing and got another problem. I am not even sure it's working properly now.

> ```
> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character (U+2003)
> ```

to which lead me to this error.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you change the compiler from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX?

Comment: `U+2003` is an em-space. You can't *see* it. Copy the correct space from wikipedia and search for this character in your document, and then remove it/them. I've seen some dirty IDE setup that treats some non-ascii spaces as the standard one. So most likely you have that space in your thesis from the beginning but changing (reinstall) the IDE ultimately reveals it.

Comment: define 2003 as FIX ME as described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396764/how-to-find-this-unicode-character-u202f-in-your-latex-documents/396766#396766  That will show in the output where you have the character then edit your source to replace them by real spaces or `\hspace{1em}` if you need an em space.